ML ColumnTransformer OneHotEncoder
When converting categorical data in first column of my dataframe I am getting strange behavior of ColumnTransformer with OneHotEncoder. the behavior occurs when I add one row to my csv file.
the initial data is:
title,dailygross,theaters,DayInYear
ACatinParis,307,5,257
ALettertoMomo,307,5,257
AnotherDayofLife,307,5,257
ApprovedforAdoption,307,5,257
AprilandtheExtraordinaryWorld,307,5,257
Belle,307,5,257
BirdboyTheForgottenChildren,307,5,257
ChicoRita,307,5,257

when running code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('../data/GKIDS_DayNum_test_names.csv')
dataset['title'].str.strip()
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

title_column_index = dataset.columns.get_loc('title')
print('title index:', title_column_index)
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [title_column_index])], remainder='passthrough')
X_Encoded = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
print(X_Encoded)

the result is correct:
[[1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 307 5]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 307 5]]

However when I add additional row: BlueGiant,307,5,257
to the file and re run the code I am getting weird output:
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 9)    307.0
  (0, 10)   5.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (1, 9)    307.0
  (1, 10)   5.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 9)    307.0
  (2, 10)   5.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (3, 9)    307.0
  (3, 10)   5.0
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (4, 9)    307.0
  (4, 10)   5.0
  (5, 5)    1.0
  (5, 9)    307.0
  (5, 10)   5.0
  (6, 6)    1.0
  (6, 9)    307.0
  (6, 10)   5.0
  (7, 8)    1.0
  (7, 9)    307.0
  (7, 10)   5.0
  (8, 7)    1.0
  (8, 9)    307.0
  (8, 10)   5.0

I do not understand why it is.
Please help.

The latter is the display for a scipy sparse array. OneHotEncoder produces sparse arrays as output, and ColumnTransformer uses a sparse array when the overall density of values of its output is below the parameter sparse_threshold.  In the first dataset, the density is exactly 0.3, the default sparse_threshold; after adding a new column in your new dataset, it's below the threshold (3/11).
The display you have lists all the nonzero entries of the output, with the location in the matrix in parentheses and the value after that. So all those 307's and 5's are your passthrough values, the 1's are the "one hot"s, and the zeros that are "not hot" are omitted (saving memory space, which is the point of this sparse storage format).
Lots of algorithms can make use of the sparse format directly, so you can likely just leave it as is. If you want a dense output, you can cast the array directly using <transformed_out>.toarray() (remove the np.array(...) from your code), setting sparse=False in the encoder, or setting sparse_threshold=0 in the column transformer.

I did not add new column, I added new categorical value. Please elaborate. Are you saying the behavior is correct? Also what happened to missed values, remainder='passthrough' so the rest of the values should not be touched.

You added a new categorical value, which adds a column to the transformed (one-hot encoded) output. Yes, the behavior is correct. I'll add a little about sparse arrays to the answer for the rest.
